# Save objects from vector with pointers to file

Tags: c++, file, pointers, vector, iterator

I have a vector with pointers to a base class object so i can manage objects derived from that class.

```
vector <Product*>  products;
```

i am trying to write these objects to a file while iterating through the vector
but i am not sure if this works correctly.

```
void Inventory ::  saveProductsToFile()
 {
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("inventory.dat",ios::binary);

    list <Product*> :: iterator it;
    for(it=products.begin(); it!=products.end(); it++)
        outfile.write((char*)*(it),sizeof(Product));
 }
```

The file is created but i have no idea if i'm saving the actual objects themselves or their
addresses.Is this correct or is there another way?

This is how the file looks like:

```
ˆFG "   H*c     \Âõ(œ@@pFG    h*c b'v      b@
```

Comment: Could you show us what the file looks like after you this function was called?

Comment: Dervied classes could be of a different size, so this will not work. Also, if there are any members that are dynamically allocated or contain dynamically allocated memory (such as `std::string`) it will also not work.

Comment: Use `sizeof(*it)` instead; and yes, as hmjd mentioned, if you class contains pointers they have to be swizzled before serializing

Comment: yes it does have dynamically allocated members!

Comment: @Paranaix `sizeof` is a constant expression, which returns the size of the _static_ type, so `sizeof(*it)` and `sizeof(Product)` will evaluate to exactly the same value.

Answer (score 1):

You code can work.  You cannot serialize polymorphic objects in
that way.  For starters, you're writing the hidden `vptr` out
to disk; when you reread the data, it will not be valid.  And
you're only writing out the data in the base class (`Product`),
because that's what `sizeof(Product)` evaluates to.  And
finally, just writing a byte image of anything but a `char[]`
will probably mean that you won't be able to reread the data
some time in the future (after a compiler upgrade, or a machine
upgrade, or whatever).

What you have to do is to define a format (binary or text) for
the file, and write that.  For the basic types, you can start
with something existing, like XDR or Protocol buffers, but
neither of these work that well with polymorphic types.  For
polymorphic types, you have to start by defining how you
identify the type in question when rereading.  This can be
tricky: there's nothing in `std::type_info` which helps, so you
need some means of establishing a relationship between your
(derived) types and the identifier.  Then every derived class
must implement a `write` function, which first writes its type,
then writes its data out, one element by one.  When reading, you
read the type, look up the appropriate read function for that
type in a map, and call that function, which then reads the data
one by one.

Finally, I might point out that all successful serialization
schemes I've seen depend on generated code.  You describe your
types in a separate file, or in special markup (in a specially
marked comment in the C++), and have a program which reads that,
and generates the necessary code (and often the actual classes
you use).

Comment: i will give the identifier method ago and see how the mapping goes!Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Thats not how you "serialize" data. Like this the pointers are only valid during runtime or until you delete them (depending on what happens/stops first). Like this you wouldn't be able to restore your data, because after the program has stopped everything from your former memory becomes invalid. You would have to store the actual values from your class.

Comment: It is the actual values i'm trying to store not the pointers.I'm using  iterators and vectors for the first time and was not sure what the particular "write" command saves to the file.

Comment: Then you need to get the actual value and give it to your ofstream object. I'm surprised that it even worked like this, because it seems like you converted the object value from Product to a const char pointer.

Comment: would something like `outfile <<  (*it)->getCode();` do the trick then?Would my data be restorable?

Comment: @thebaconing What he's written will write some bytes to the file; in that sense, it will "work".  There's no way he'll be able to reread them, however.  Writing the `vptr` is _not_ going to help, for example.

Comment: @Spapo It depends on what `Product::getCode` does in each of the derived classes.  It could certainly be made to work (although I'd probably tend to something like `(*it)->serialize( outfile )`).  But you're still faced with the problem of what to put into the different `getCode` functions.

Comment: @James Kanze :what i mean by the actual data is e.g. when he calculates the Product of a number "6*3=18" and stores the result in his class, he would write the result "18" to file. To clarify the terms of serialization it is only possible to do it with "PODs".

Comment: @thebaconing I'm not sure I understand.  If the output format is text, then you can only output types for which `<<` is defined.  If the output format is binary...  There are no binary formatting output operators, so you have to write the code by hand.  In either case, whether the type is a POD or not has nothing to do with it.